# Why does Windows Explorer allow creation of folders which are too long to be moved by Directory.Move - producing PathTooLongException?

Tags: .net, windows, filesystems, windows-explorer, system.io.directory

I am able to manually create a folder in Windows Explorer, full path is exactly 247 characters long (excluding trailing slash). As far as I understand, 248 is the max folder name path limit, including the trailing slash.

Then I try to use `Directory.Move` method to rename this folder to a shorter path:

```
string folder247CharsLong = @"C:\first level folder path - will form 247 chars\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";

string folder215CharsLong = @"C:\first level folder path - will form 247 chars\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\SHORT";

Directory.Move(folder247CharsLong, folder215CharsLong);
```

This throws `PathTooLongException` - saying "The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters".

I assume this is because Directory.Move appends a trialing slash and then checks (path +"\").Length < 248.

Directory.Delete method with the same path does not throw.

I assume the problem is that Windows Explorer allows creation of such folder, can anyone confirm if this is faulty Windows Explorer behavior or a bug in Directory.Move?

Comment: I always have the same question, my current answer to myself is: _This is a difference between Windows API(Windows Explorer) and .net framework._

Answer (score -1):

It depends of the version of the API functions used to refer to the files/folders and the namespace they are using.

In the Windows API the maximum length for a path is 260, but unicode versions of the API functions handle a extended length of 32767 characters.

See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Microsoft documentation for a complete reference.

Comment: can you please clarify how is the version of the API functions being used different in Windows Explorer vs. the .NET BCL? Can you provide a source describing different versions of the API functions? I am pretty familiar with the link you posted. While max file path length is 260, folder names must be less than 248 chars long. My question is why there is a difference between .NET BCL and Windows Explorer.  I cannot use the "extended length paths" - too many other issues with them

Comment: @Marek, Not sure if you also know it, but [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) you will find more information.

Comment: Now I understand you are referring to unicode vs. standard file APIs with "versions of API functions". Do you have any reference stating that Windows Explorer internally uses the 32767-limited APIs, while only artificially limiting path lengths?